# ruby on rails beginner: rails for zombies code sample

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-for-zombies

where does that @user in the code in check_ammo come from? 
see code for "weapon" in model, controller, mailer and schema.rb

[rails for zombies code](https://github.com/codeschool/RFZ2-ZombieTweets/blob/master/app/models/weapon.rb)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your questions. It doesn't come from anywhere; I don't see why it'd be anything other than `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code cant be right.
Weaponmailer

```
  def low_ammo(weapon, zombie)
    attachments["weapon.jpg"] = weapon.picture_file
    mail to: zombie.email, subject: "#{weapon.name} has low ammo"
  end
```

expects 2 parameters in controller

```
 WeaponMailer.low_ammo(@user).deliver
```

@user is not defined unless its defined in ActiveRecord::Base what is not the case i think. Its just broken code example